# Canvas. Как "вырезать" дырку в фигуре другой фигурой?

Tags: canvas

**Процесс**. Сanvas_ом рисую перекрывающий всё содержание страницы прямоугольник. Далее, задача сделать в этом прямоугольнике дырку в форме овала, и чтобы внутри этого овала видимое содержимое страницы было активное. Делаю так:

```
    ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"; // Задаем цвет с прозрачностью для фона
     ctx.fillRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Рисуем фон на всю страницу
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // При наслоении объектов вычитаем один из другого

    // Рисуем овал-дырку
    ctx.beginPath();
     drawEllipse(ctx, left, top, width, height);
    ctx.closePath();
```

**Проблема**: содержимое страницы внутри овала не активное. Т.е. содержимое нельзя выделять, кликать и тд.

z-index_ом поднять нужное содержимое не вариант, так как выделение в форме овала, а содержимое может быть в форме прямоугольника, где часть прямоугольника не выделено, а часть выделено.

**Вопрос**: как сделать дырку такой, чтобы она давала доступ к содержанию внутри себя.

Comment: Наверное проблема в том, что canvas - это прямоугольный прозрачный элемент на вашей странице. Когда вы вырезаете дырку, то canvas никуда не девается.